# Check name to import value on the tab

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know if I can reference the formula to the name in column A to get the values in the same name of the tab.

[image: Sample]

My formula is `=vlookup(round((Aimee!$B$4*24),2),Export!M18:N74,2,0)`

There is an Aimee tab and the name to be referenced is in column A (Aimee).

Answer (score 1):

`=vlookup(INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$14"),Export!$E$9:$F$11,2,false)`

---

- Use INDIRECT` to return the content of a cell
- `INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$14"): takes the sheet name represented by the value in Cell A1 Sheet "Dash", and addresses the specific lookup cell of "$B$14"
- Note that this answer expresses the VLOOKUP `range` as absolute, on the basis that as the formula is to be copied down the rows of Column O, one assumes that the lookupup range would remain constant.